Why does Apache PDFBox fill a multi-line text field differently than Acrobat Reader?
When I manually enter the data, here is what shows:

When I fill the text field using the code shown below, here is what shows:

Why the difference in vertical placement?
Thank you for any assistance you can give.

Here are some notes that may or may not be relevant:
The template pdf is available at:
https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/f1065sk1.pdf
Getting this warning:
WARNING: Using fallback font Helvetica for HelveticaLTStd-Roman

The IRS forms are created with Adobe LiveCycle Designer, an application that only runs on Windows and costs many thousands of dollars. As such I cannot edit the PDF with Acrobat Pro.

Here is minimal code to duplicate the problem.
package util.pdf.box;

import util.file.BytesToFile;
import util.file.FileToBytes;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocument;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.PDDocumentCatalog;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDAcroForm;
import org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.form.PDField;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;

public class PdfFormFiller {

    public byte[] fill(
        byte[] template,
        String key,
        String value
    ) {

        byte[] pdfBytes = new byte[]{};
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        try (
            PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load(template)
        ) {
            PDDocumentCatalog pdDocCatalog = doc.getDocumentCatalog( );
            PDAcroForm acroForm = pdDocCatalog.getAcroForm();
            PDField field = acroForm.getField(key);
            field.setValue(value);
            doc.save(baos);
        } catch ( Exception e ) {
            System.out.println( e.getMessage( ) );
        }
        pdfBytes = baos.toByteArray( );
        return pdfBytes;

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String filePath = "/Users/johndoe/f1065sk1.pdf";
        byte[] pdfBytes = FileToBytes.readFile( filePath );
        PdfFormFiller pdfFormFiller = new PdfFormFiller( );
        byte[] pdfFilled = pdfFormFiller.fill(
            pdfBytes,
            "topmostSubform[0].Page1[0].LeftCol[0].f1_7[0]",
            "Name\nAddress\nCity, State Zip"
        );
        String outDirName = "/Users/johndoe";
        String outFileName = "f1065sk1.filled.pdf";
        BytesToFile.writeToDirFile( pdfFilled, outDirName, outFileName );

    }

}



What is your question about, the blue background or the slight size difference? I got the blue background only in firefox, not with Adobe Reader. Don't bother about the font warning, the fallback font is similar. Or install that font on your computer.

The vertical placement causes the last line to be vertically truncated. That is my focus.

You should [edit] the question to clarify the actual problem.

ah ok, then you can change the /DA entry of that field, from "/HelveticaLTStd-Roman 10.00 Tf 0 g" to "/HelveticaLTStd-Roman 9 Tf 0 g" by calling setDefaultAppearance().

"Why the difference in vertical placement?" - Essentially that is because the details of multi-line textfields are not cleanly specified in the PDF specification. Pdfbox developers try to imitate Acrobat behavior but as it's not documented, either, that does not always work as desired.

Does the PDFBox API have way to adjust the vertical positioning?

No, the vertical start is calculated internally.

I followed Tillman's recommendation and added these lines of code:
PDTextField pdTextField = (PDTextField) field;
pdTextField.setDefaultAppearance( "/HelveticaLTStd-Roman 9 Tf 0 g" );
pdTextField.setValue(value);

This is a workaround as seen below.
But it seems to me that the root problem is extra margin/padding in the top of the text field. See #1.
But what is there is acceptable.

